# rysnc error while coping a file to another server

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I need to send a large 410mb file from one sever to another.

I am trying to use rsync with the following command but keep getting this error:

```
rysnc -avz -e "ssh -p 44" username@123.123.123.123:/var/www/xml.tar /var/www/xml.tar

rynsc error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(605) [reveiver=3.0.9]
```

But if i do not set the name of the destination and only the target folder:

```
rysnc -avz -e "ssh -p 44" username@123.123.123.123:/var/www/xml.tar /var/www/
```

I get:

```
rynsc error: error in rysnc protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [reciever=3.0.9]
```

The remote server is Ubuntu 11.04 and the local machine I am trying to copy the .tar onto is ubuntu 12.04..

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks,
John

PS/
ssh -p 44 user@ip works fine, also the file path on the remote and local is correct too..

Comment: if you're just copying a single file, I'd try scp

Comment: thanks, this worked a charm: spc -P 1234 user@[ip address or host name]:/var/www/mywebsite/dumps/* /var/www/myNewPathOnCurrentLocalMachine

Comment: great... don't forget that you can copy recursively with scp (-r)... here are a few other examples: http://afj-phd.blogspot.ca/2007/08/copying-multiple-files-with-scp.html